# Error when finding value in pymongo Mongodb

Tags: python, database, mongodb, networking, pymongo

### Code

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.zcui8.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")
db = client["db"]

#this gives the error
res = list(db.listings.find({}).limit(15).sort([('$natural',-1)]))
```

### Error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members found yet
```

I get this error in the line where I assign the variable `res`.
And I don't get this error when run it on my machine, but when i run it on a server i get the error.

Comment: did you add the new IP address -  of your application server -  to the allowed list on Atlas ?

Comment: No i added `0.0.0.0` so everyone should be able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is usually:

- Not using the latest `pymongo` drivers
  (https://pypi.org/project/pymongo/ list the current latest version)
- Not having the `dnspython` module installed (I had issues 2.1.0 so
  would recommend 2.0.0)

Comment: I have dnspython, how can I update pymongo to the latest on Cpanel ?

Comment: No idea never used it.

Comment: if you have access to the command line, you can run:

"python pip install pymongo"

or

"sudo python pip install pymongo"

Comment: I updated pymongo and made sure dnspython is version 2.0.0 and still got this error:
`pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: No replica set members found yet, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 617d23fae48c883eebfe53be, topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-00.zuia8.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None>, <ServerDescription ('cluster0-shard-00-01.zuia8.mongodb.net', 27017) server_type: Unkn`

Answer (score 0):

I tried every solution in these answers but the only thing that worked is just
using the `flask_pymongo` module instead of `pymongo`. And now i don't get any errors.